# span inside input field and remove html text when i submit

Tags: php, html, css

I am new to php, I want my span to be displayed in the input field and after submitting the form, I hate this * required field and * continue to display.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>  

<?php
<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?> </span>
  <br><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Website: <input type="text" name="website" value="<?php echo $website;?>">
  <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
  <br><br>
  Gender:
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender==="female") {echo "checked";}?>>Female
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender==="male") {echo "checked";}?>>Male
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender==="other") {echo "checked";}?>>Other
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: You send the form with post or get? Tip : You should append your code for help you better!

Comment: Please add the html / css of the form to you question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't place it inside the input.

You can use absolute positioning inside a container to place it on top of the input:

```css
.input-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.input-container .error {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    font-style: italic;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 15px; 
}

input[type="text"] {
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
    <div class="field-container">
        <label for="name">Name *</label>
        <div class="input-container">
            <input id="name" type="text" name="name" value="" />
            <span class="error">* This field should not be empty</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- repeat for other fields -->
</form>
```

If you only want to show the error when there is one:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['name']) && strlen($nameErr) > 0): ?>
    <span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here I assume the variable is an empty string when there is no error.

Comment: where is .field-container can you please explain